# react pass props from child back to parent

Tags: reactjs

lets say we have 3 react components, the first will be the parent, the second will be his child, and the third will be the child of the second component.
so i want to pass props from the third one back to the first one, to use it in a function.
code example:

```js
class leveOne extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            blabla: bla.
        }
    }

    consoleLogChildren = () => {
        console.log(//here lets console.log the childrens props)
    }

    render(){
       return(
           <LevelTwo propsFromLevelThree={props}/>
       )
    }
}

class leveTwo extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <LevelThree propsFromLevelThree={props}/>
       )
    }
}

class leveThree extends React.Component{
    render(){
       return(
          <h1 props={props to pass back to LevelOne}>LEVEL3</h1>
       )
    }
}
```

hope my question is clear /:
seen a lot of info about this but nothing was clear to me thank guys

Comment: probably you want this: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html maybe this: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Comment: the best way would be to use global state management, take look at react context API, or for more complex projects I recommend redux.

Comment: Or you can pass a function as prop and use it as callback in the children to pass something to the parent.

Comment: if you want to pass prop go down through many components better to use state management. So you can avoid having complex components.

Comment: @sashiksu State and props are two different things. Storing props in state is anti-pattern. State management also doesn't really work for callback functions, which is what OP is wanting to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the simple process of passing props down from parent to child. Notice that `LevelTwo` is passing along *all* the props that were passed to it, and then adding more of it's own.

```js
class LevelThree extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>LEVEL3</h1>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => this.props.consoleLogChildren(this.props)}
        >
          consoleLogChildren
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class LevelTwo extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <LevelThree {...this.props} testProp="this is a test prop"/>
    )
  }
}

class LevelOne extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      blabla: 'bla.'
    }
  }

  consoleLogChildren = (...args) => {
    console.log(...args);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <LevelTwo consoleLogChildren={this.consoleLogChildren}/>
    )
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <LevelOne />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

But this pattern can be abused and lead to an issue known as "Props Drilling" where every component between needs to ensure the pass all props on to their children. You can resolve this issue by using the Context API. The allows you to provide a value in a context and intermediate children don't need to explicitly pass along props they don't care about.

```js
const PropContext = React.createContext({
  consoleLogChildren: () => {}
});

const PropContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const consoleLogChildren = (...args) => {
    console.log(...args);
  };

  return (
    <PropContext.Provider value={{ consoleLogChildren }}>
      {children}
    </PropContext.Provider>
  );
};

class LevelThree extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>LEVEL3</h1>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => this.props.consoleLogChildren(this.props)}
        >
          consoleLogChildren
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class LevelTwo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <PropContext.Consumer>
        {({ consoleLogChildren }) => (
          <LevelThree
            consoleLogChildren={consoleLogChildren}
            testProp="this is a test prop"
          />
        )}
      </PropContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}

class LevelOne extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      blabla: "bla."
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <PropContextProvider>
        <LevelTwo />
      </PropContextProvider>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <LevelOne />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing passing a function by props may be simplest solution here, if you don't want to use any global state.

The function would set parents state.
Something like that:

```
class LeveOne extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          blabla: 'bla'
      }
  }

  consoleLogChildren = () => {
      console.log(this.state)
  }

  setBlaBla = (bla) => this.setState({blabla: bla});

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render(){
     return(
      <div>
        <LevelTwo propsFromLevelOne={{setBlaBla: this.setBlaBla}}/>
        <p>{this.state.blabla}</p> {/* <-- it should be rendered as "hello from level 3!" */}
      </div>
     )
  }
}

class LevelTwo extends React.Component{
  render(){
      return(
          <LevelThree propsFromLevelTwo={this.props.propsFromLevelOne}/>
     )
  }
}

class LevelThree extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.propsFromLevelTwo.setBlaBla('hello from level 3!');
  }
  render(){
     return(
        <h1 props={}>LEVEL3</h1>
     )
  }
}
```